# Parsing a Main URL then parse all siblings URLS

Tags: python, csv, url, beautifulsoup

i can scrape all the urls from the https://gg.co.uk/tips/today web site this gives me a list like below i can store these in a links.csv file ie
https://gg.co.uk/racing/16-jun-2020/thirsk-1300
https://gg.co.uk/racing/16-jun-2020/thirsk-1330
ect
ect

i would like to scrape each URL in turn to produce the siblings URLs ie
https://gg.co.uk//racing/form-profile-2402075
ect
ect
and save this list to a urls to a file eg output.csv

Comment: In beautifulsoup you can use the `find_all` function and find all `a` tags and scrape the `href` content

Comment: thank you for your replay - i already have this code to find_all the parent links from the online html file 'https://gg.co.uk/tips/today' but i can not seem to find any code or get working a python/beautifulsoup example that allow me to parse  the links.csv file with a colume full of links ie: https://gg.co.uk/racing/16-jun-2020/thirsk-1300 https://gg.co.uk/racing/16-jun-2020/thirsk-1330 ect,,ect and scrape these links to out put the racing/form-profile-2402075 ect ect can you help please .

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show what code you have so far. You need to have a nested request / beautifulsoup call.